# What are good ways to keep GridBagConstraints under control?

Tags: java, swing

I'm somewhat new to Swing programming, and I find that as much as I love the power of GridBagLayout, if you've got a lot of components, there are lots of lines of code just setting up the constraints for the layout. What are some good ways to keep this under control, besides using a visual editor?

Comment: Check out MigLayout instead of GridBagLayout - http://www.miglayout.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel your pain. I feel it so much, that I have recently abandoned GridBagLayout entirely, in favor of another tool - [JGoodies Forms](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/forms/). Its layout code is more concise, reads at a higher level, and is in general much more satisfying to use than GridBagLayout.

It defines a mini-language to define layouts. It's cryptic at first glance, but don't let that discourage you.

If you are able to use it in your environment, I would highly recommend it.

Comment: I checked it out - really great. A huge improvement over GBL.

Comment: You may also check out DesignGridLayout (http://designgridlayout.dev.java.net) which does the same as JGoodies forms but exclusively through its API, which prevents any possible problem in runtime (if it compiles, it will run correctly!)

Answer (score 3):

Remember that when you add `GridBagConstraints` to a `GridBagLayout` the data is copied (actually cloned). Therefore, you don't need to start from scratch for each component you add.

You may find the double-brace idiom useful.

I recommend using a better builder than `GridBagConstraints` public fields. My original answer had a link to a now defunct blog entry on the subject for an example. IIRC, a class extending `GridBagConstraints` with method returning this. I forget all the extras, but there were methods that set multiple fields (say, `gridx` and `gridy`), increments and more exotics things.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GridBagLayout is really painful. But it's still powerful. In many cases, you cannot escape from it. Lets check this tiny utility to see it it ease your pain [painless-gridbag](http://code.google.com/p/painless-gridbag/)