# Code Organization Standard

Tags: java

I am required to manually hand code all GUI's for my school assignments. I am working with Java and using GridBagLayout. I read that it is not a good idea to reuse the same GridBagConstraint instance and instead for each component to have it's own GridBagConstraint instance. So if each component gets its own and I specify fill, position, and insets for each one that leads to a lot of lines of code just for the GUI.

This particular assignment I will have a main pane in BorderLayout and 2 other panes that will sit inside that. One will be another BorderLayout that is just a display area for output information, the other will be the labels, text fields and buttons for a user to select multiple files to be used for input. I have broken it down and placed all code for each pane in its own JComponent instance(not sure if that is the correct term). So code looks like:

```
protected JComponent inputPaneComponent() {
    all code for the inputPane goes here
}
```

But like I described above using multiple GridBagConstraints and specifics for each component leads to a long group of code. Should I break it apart with empty lines between each component maybe put a comment line above each one stating which component I am working with? Or just a long stack of lines?

This is just a sample I haven't finished coding it all yet. Something like this:

```
protected JComponent inputPaneComponent() {
    JPanel inputPane = new JPanel();
    inputPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    inputPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Input Files:"));
    GridBagConstraints c0 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c0.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c0.gridx = 0;
    c0.gridy = 0;
    c0.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
    inputPane.add(nameLabel, c0);
    GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c1.gridx = 1;
    c1.gridy = 0;
    c1.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
    inputPane.add(nameFileTextField, c1);
    GridBagConstraints c2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c2.gridx = 2;
    c2.gridy = 0;
    c2.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
    inputPane.add(nameFileButton, c2);
    return inputPane;
}
```

or This:

```
protected JComponent inputPaneComponent() {
    // Set title, layout, and exit condition.
    JPanel inputPane = new JPanel();
    inputPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    inputPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Input Files:"));

    // Create and configure name label.
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Names File:");
    GridBagConstraints c0 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c0.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c0.gridx = 0;
    c0.gridy = 0;
    c0.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
    inputPane.add(nameLabel, c0);

    // Create and configure name file textfield.
    JTextField nameFileTextField = new JTextField(60);
    GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c1.gridx = 1;
    c1.gridy = 0;
    c1.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
    inputPane.add(nameFileTextField, c1);

    // Create and configure name file button.
    JButton nameFileButton = new JButton("Browse");
    GridBagConstraints c2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c2.gridx = 2;
    c2.gridy = 0;
    c2.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);
    inputPane.add(nameFileButton, c2);
    return inputPane;
}
```

I prefer the latter, as to me it is easier to read, but it does add to the length and I'm not that experienced and would like to know what the standard might be.

Thanks for your help, and I hope I'm within the rules for this forum, this is my first post here.

Matt

Comment: In the end, it's your code and the functionality is the most important piece. Your question, however, is opinion based, please read [what is considered on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Easier to read and easier to understand adds up to improved maintainability, which is always good.  The second snippet that you've shown is far superior to the first.  Another really good alternative would be to put all the GridBagConstraints-related code into its own method.  Maybe with a signature like `private void addToPanel(JPanel panel, JComponent item, int gridx, int gridy)`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly ... No, there is no standard, or defacto standard, apart from using a designer tool<sup>1</sup> that *generates* the low-level layout code.  (Which you have been told not to do.)

However, there are potential ways to make your task a bit less painful:

- The `GridBagConstraint` object is cloned when it is incorporated into a `GridBagLayout`.  That means you can reuse the same `GridBagConstraint` object, making incremental changes to it.
- There are third-party libraries that provide a "builder" for `GridBagConstraint` objects that are designed to make construction more concise.

Read this Q&A for more some leads:

- [What are good ways to keep GridBagConstraints under control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1446039/139985)

---

<sup>1 - The trap with designer tools is that you get "locked in" to using a specific tool.  That is fine ... until the tool vendor stops supporting it.  Another problem is that you may discover that you need to pay an exorbitant fee for runtime licenses in order to distribute / sell your product.  (I have seen that one kill a good project, stone dead!)</sup>

Comment: Good answer, though I’m not a fan of that link;  it consists almost entirely of GridBagLayout alternatives rather than good advice on GridBagLayout usage.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to refactor your code because in general, lengthy methods is they are NOT easily supportable/maintainable, so you need to `refactor` your lengthy methods further to smaller methods with meaningful names so that you can avoid the comments as well as the method names become self-explanatory  and they become more readable/understandable.

You can refer the below methods that I have refactored some of your code to the following as below:

```
    private GridBagConstraints populateNameLabel(JLabel nameLabel) {
        //populate the data here and return
    }

    private GridBagConstraints populateTextField(JTextField nameFileTextField) {
        //populate the data here and return
    }

    private GridBagConstraints populateFileButton(JButton nameFileButton) {
        //populate the data here and return
    }
```

You need to make use of these methods in your original method so that the code becomes more supportable/readable.

Comment: Thank you for the input, much appreciated.

Comment: @Matt Can you accept my answer if it is helpful ?